# How to add underscores and remove them when the user inputs the correct letter?

Tags: ruby

I'm having difficulty in adding underscores in my program. Also what is troubling me is that I can't seem to figure out how to remove the underscores when the user inputs the correct letter.

```rb
class Game

attr_reader :guess_count, :is_over, :word_length

def initialize (secret_word)
    @secret_word = secret_word
    @guess_count = 0 
    @is_over = false 
    @word_length = secret_word.length
end 

def check_word(guess)
    @guess_count += 1
    if @secret_word == guess 
        puts "Congratulations!"
        @is_over = true 
    else 
        @is_over = false
        puts "Sorry, try again!"
    end 
end 

def subtract_guess_count
    counter = @word_length - @guess_count
end 

end

puts "User 1, What is your secret word?"
secret_word = gets.chomp

anything = Game.new(secret_word)

while !anything.is_over
    puts "User 2, Guess the secret word"
        guess = gets.chomp
    anything.check_word(guess)
        if anything.subtract_guess_count == 0
            puts "You lose! the correct word was #{secret_word}"
            exit!
        end 
        if anything.is_over == false
            puts "You have #{anything.subtract_guess_count} left!"
        end 
end
```

Comment: Input contains underscore? That you want to remove? If so, use this `gets.chomp.gsub("_","")`

Comment: I'm not sure how to come about it, for more clarity here's what i need to do.



**#The guessing player receives continual feedback on the current state of the word. So if the secret word is "unicorn", the user will start out seeing something like "_ _ _ _ _ _ _", which would become "_ _ _ c _ _ _" after the user enters a guess of "c".**

i would like to have the program run underscores instead of blank

Answer (score 0):

*Major Edit*

To create a string of underscores you can do this:

```
word = ""
1.upto(@secret_word.length) do
    word << "_"
end
```

To replace a character with an underscore (and vice versa) in a ruby string you can use the syntax:

```
word[i] = "_"
```

To print a word with spaces between each letter you can use the following:

```
array = word.split(//)
array.join(" ")
```

For your code a check_letter function could be useful:

```
def check_letter (guess)
    if (@secret_word[guess])
        for i in 0..((@secret_word.length) -1 )
            if @secret_word[i] == guess
                @progress[i] = guess 
            end
        end
    end
    show_progress
    check_word(@progress)    
end
```

*Working code*

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
#
class Game

    attr_reader :guess_count, :is_over, :word_length, :progress

    def initialize (secret_word)
        @secret_word = secret_word
        @guess_count = 0 
        @is_over = false 
        @word_length = secret_word.length
        @progress = ""
        1.upto(secret_word.length) do
            @progress << "_"
        end 
    end 

    def check_word(guess)
        if @secret_word == guess 
            puts "Congratulations!"
            @is_over = true 
        else 
            @is_over = false
            puts "Sorry, try again!"
        end 
    end 

    def check_letter (guess)
        if (@secret_word[guess])
            for i in 0..((@secret_word.length) -1 )
                if @secret_word[i] == guess
                    @progress[i] = guess 
                end
            end
        end
        show_progress
        check_word(@progress)    
    end

    def show_progress
        array = @progress.split(//)
        word = ""
        array.each  do |letter|
            word << letter + " "
        end
        puts word 
    end

    def one_less_guess
        @guess_count += 1
    end

    def subtract_guess_count
        counter = @word_length - @guess_count
    end 
end

puts "User 1, What is your secret word?"
secret_word = gets.chomp

anything = Game.new(secret_word)

while !anything.is_over
    puts "User 2, Guess the secret word"
    guess = gets.chomp
    anything.one_less_guess
    if guess.length == 1
        anything.check_letter(guess)
    else
        anything.check_word(guess)
    end
    if anything.subtract_guess_count == 0
        puts "You lose! the correct word was #{secret_word}"
        exit!
    end 
    if anything.is_over == false
        puts "You have #{anything.subtract_guess_count} left!"
    end 
end
```

Comment: i've added all the things you posted and it still doesnt show the underscore.

Comment: i've added the codes you posted and it still doesn't show the underscores, sorry i'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Thank you! after going over it, it finally makes sense to me now!

Comment: Your welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer and vote for it.